# How to make a button in a parent container trigger a function in children not known ahead in time?

Tags: reactjs

Basically when a user clicks “Add Item”, I show a bunch of options like Add Note, Add Link, Add Photo and so on. Whenever one of these options is clicked, I slot in the relevant component I.e `ItemTextScreen`, `ItemLinkScreen`, `ItemPhotoScreen` in the `ContentDialog` via the `AddItem`.

Now my challenge is, what is the ideal way to allow a button click like “Save” to trigger a handleSubmit implementation inside `ItemTextScreen`. I’m new to React so forgive my ignorance. Currently , `ContentDialog` lives in the `AddItem` and waits for the impending option click whereby it takes in one of the `ItemTextScreen`, `ItemLinkScreen`, `ItemPhotoScreen`.

Basically I’ve researched into `imperativeHandle` and `refs` but I am not sure if these are the Reacty ways of doing things or if I should be doing it differently.

[image]

**ContentDialog.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";

export default function ContentDialog(props) {

  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);
  const bigScreen = useMediaQuery((theme) => theme.breakpoints.up("md"));

  useEffect(() => {
    setToggle(props.open);
  }, [props.open]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        fullScreen={!bigScreen}
        open={toggle}
        onClose={props.handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="scroll-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="scroll-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="scroll-dialog-title">{props.title}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          {props.children}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={props.handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button>Save</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**AddItem.js**

```
import ArticleOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArticleOutlined";
import AudioItem from "./Screens/ItemAudioScreen";
import BookmarkBorderOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/BookmarkBorderOutlined";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import ButtonGroup from "@mui/material/ButtonGroup";
import ContentDialog from "@/components/dialogs/ContentDialog";
import LinkItem from "./Screens/ItemLinkScreen";
import MicNoneOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MicNoneOutlined";
import PhotoItem from "./Screens/ItemPhotoScreen";
import PhotoOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PhotoOutlined";
import TextItem from "./Screens/ItemTextScreen";
import VideoItem from "./Screens/ItemVideoScreen";
import VideoLibraryOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/VideoLibraryOutlined";
import { grey } from "@mui/material/colors";
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";
import { useState } from "react";

function AddItem() {
  const bigScreen = useMediaQuery((theme) => theme.breakpoints.up("md"));
  const orientation = bigScreen ? "horizontal" : "vertical";

  const [currentItemComponent, setCurrentItemComponent] = useState(null);
  const [openContentDialog, setOpenContentDialog] = useState(false);

  const handleOpenContentDialog = (itemComponent) => {
    setCurrentItemComponent(itemComponent);
    setOpenContentDialog(true);
  };

  const handleCloseContentDialog = () => {
    setOpenContentDialog(false);
  };
  return (
    <Box sx={{ ml: { md: 3 } }}>
      <ContentDialog
        open={openContentDialog}
        handleClose={handleCloseContentDialog}
      >
        {currentItemComponent}
      </ContentDialog>
      <ButtonGroup
        fullWidth
        orientation={orientation}
        size="medium"
        color="primary"
        aria-label="large button group"
      >
        <Button
          onClick={() => handleOpenContentDialog(<TextItem title="Note" />)}
        >
          <ArticleOutlinedIcon sx={{ mr: 1 }} /> Write a Note
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => handleOpenContentDialog(<PhotoItem title="Photo" />)}
        >
          <PhotoOutlinedIcon sx={{ mr: 1 }} /> Upload a Photo
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => handleOpenContentDialog(<VideoItem title="Video" />)}>
          <VideoLibraryOutlinedIcon sx={{ mr: 1 }} /> Embed a Video
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => handleOpenContentDialog(<AudioItem title="Audio" />)}>
          <MicNoneOutlinedIcon sx={{ mr: 1 }} /> Record an Audio
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => handleOpenContentDialog(<LinkItem title="Link" />)}>
          <BookmarkBorderOutlinedIcon sx={{ mr: 1 }} /> Bookmark a Link
        </Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default AddItem;
```

**ItemTextScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react'

function TextItem() {

const submit = () => {
    console.log('submit');
}
    
  return (
    <div>Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta.</div>
  )
}

export default TextItem
```

Comment: Do you want to kown how to get information from formData that submited in son components.You are arriving soon,if you kown refs and imperativeHandle.When user click the "submit" button in son components, constructing data and send it out  by “imperativeHandle”.And the callback function will be triggered in parent component

Comment: I’m not sure if my whole idea of solving the problem is correct. I’m having double thoughts. I read that using refs was bad practice.

Comment: Can you provide code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have provided code now, please check @JevonCochran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is not the most common, and it should probably be an indicator that the way your code is structured is not the most sustainable (scalable, maintainable, understandable...). But it is done and it works fine.

Here's the basic idea:

```
function Parent() {
  const childControls = useRef({})
  const onClick = () => childControls.current.toggle()
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClick}>click me</button>
      <Child controls={childControls} />
    </>
  )
}

function Child({ controls }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false)
  useImperativeHandle(controls, () => ({
    toggle: () => setState(!state),
  }))
  return <p>{state ? "I was clicked" : "I wasn't clicked"}</p>
}
```

Now at this point, you could swap `<Child>` at any point and it would still work, assuming that whichever component you swap it for also knows to do the `useImperativeHandle` part.

```
function Parent() {
  const childControls = useRef({})
  const onClick = () => childControls.current.toggle()
  const [which, setWhich] = useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClick}>click me</button>
      {which && <Child controls={childControls} />}
      {!which && <Other controls={childControls} />}
    </>
  )
}
```

And going even more abstract, if even `Parent` doesn't know in advance which child will be slot in, you can make use of `cloneElement` to inject props into a child:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child />
    </Parent>
  )
}

function Parent({ children }) {
  const childControls = useRef({})
  const onClick = () => childControls.current.toggle()
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClick}>click me</button>
      {cloneElement(children, {controls: childControls})}
    </>
  )
}
```

---

A more "standard" way of doing this would be to restore the proper "direction" in the control flow of your component tree: `Dialog` should be the last component in the tree since it needs data from one of the `ItemFoo` types to be able to function. Here's what that would look like:

```
const OPTIONS = [
  Child1,
  Child2,
]

export default function App() {
  const [option, setOption] = useState(0)
  const Component = OPTIONS[option]
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setOption(0)}>option 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setOption(1)}>option 2</button>
      <Component />
    </>
  )
}

function Child1() {
  return (
    <Dialog onClick={() => console.log("click from #1")}>
      <p>content from #1</p>
    </Dialog>
  )
}

function Dialog({
  children,
  onClick,
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
      <button onClick={onClick}>click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I structure my code that I don't have to use `refs` and also, I always wondered why did the React team supply a feature that is a bad practice? Note that all I want is a Dialog "Save" button to trigger a handleSubmit in each of the non-deterministic child components, since that makes my code more organised. But I am willing to change my mind if I am shown a better way.

Comment: Using refs is definitely not a bad practice at all. They're used everywhere all of the time and for many different reasons. What is usually considered a bad practice is to "reverse the flow" of control. In theory in react, control flows in one direction only, parent controls the child, parent passes props to the child... And with refs, you have the ability to expose functions from a child back to the parent, it's kind of like passing props in the opposite direction.

Comment: Got it. So what you are saying is that it is like a superpower that should be used sparingly or else it can be destructive. In my case, I can technically pass a handleSubmit button from a Dialog to a Child, but then it becomes messy especially when the form validation inside those Children can't be triggered externally, and only internally, for obvious reasons. I am a React noob so I just wanted to get expert opinion that I am not going batshit crazy with refs.

Comment: This is not crazy, it's just not expected (so in a big codebase with many contributors, this might trip some of them) and can result in spaghetti code if overused. But sometimes the alternative is worse.

Comment: A "more react-y" way of doing it (like the example i added at the end of my post) would be to just pass props to `Dialog` so it can "reconstruct" what it needs. You can pass a function component `component={Child}`, you can pass an element `component={<Child />}`, and of course functions, text... and then since the submit button is owned by `Dialog`, it's `Dialog`'s job to put it all back together. That's the "standard" way, but that too can get pretty messy.

Comment: I saw your updated answer. I am getting the hang of it, slowly. Thanks for your patience. So, I think the problem with the `handleSubmit` being owned by the Dialog seems like a lock in, since I loose the flexibility of customisation of handling the submit within each of those Children differently. Also, I am using React Hook Form, whereby each Child is going to have a Form, so I said, to trigger the validation inside the from an external button would only be possible by a `refs`. Have a look at my code samples for more context to grasp what I am trying to say.

Comment: @AliGajani I actually got a better idea, edited my answer. This seems clean to me, so if that works for your `Dialog` system, i'd advise to go with that solution.

Comment: Interesting idea actually. Let me try and see. So Dialog should be in the child as opposed to the Child in the Dialog. Bear in mind, I want to make my DialogContainer usable for other things in future too, so goal is reusability.

Comment: Your dialog need an `onClick` and some content if i understand correctly. This hasn't changed and works fine with my proposal. That looks reusable to me ;-)

Comment: @AliGajani If you think I earned the bounty, this is a reminder that it will expire soon. If not, please let me know what my answer is missing.

Comment: You earned it ;)

Answer (score 0):

@AliGajani, if you are using React Hook Form, it can be made simpler.

- Wrap the ContentDialog element in AddItem.js with the FormProvider from React Hook Form.
- Use the useFormContext hook to access the form methods anywhere inside its children.
- Write the submit action handler in AddItem.js
- Pass it as a prop to ContentDialog which will then attach it to the save button as a callback.
- Wrap the {currentItemComponent} with form tag and define the fields inside the respective elements - ItemTextScreen etc.
- Pass the form data to the submit handler.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't think this is the cleanest approach IMHO